# Error when trying to extract the information from Polygon OSMNX

Tags: python, osmnx

When I try to extract information from the Manhattan polygon:

```
import osmnx as ox

city = ox.geocode_to_gdf(['Manhattan, New York, USA'])

G = ox.graph_from_polygon(city, network_type='drive', simplify=True)
G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_nx, nodes=True, edges=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is this due to the fact that `city` is a `MultiPolygon`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `city` variable is a geopandas GeoDataFrame. The `graph_from_polygon` function expects the `polygon` argument to be of type shapely Polygon or MultiPolygon. See [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_polygon). You're passing it an argument of the wrong type.

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
city = ox.geocode_to_gdf(['Manhattan, New York, USA'])
polygon = city.iloc[0]['geometry']
G = ox.graph_from_polygon(polygon, network_type='drive', simplify=True)
G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_nx, nodes=True, edges=True)
```

Comment: Ohh of course, I completely forgot to get the geometry. Thank you so much